# excel sumproduct with condition and subfunction

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I use this function in LibreOffice, and I want to use this table in Excel too, but didn't work:

```
SUMPRODUCT(YEAR('m1'!$A$2:$A$5000)=2011;WEEKNUM('m1'!$A$2:$A$5000;2)=24;WEEKDAY('m1'!$A$2:$A$5000;2)=3;'m1'!$K$2:$K$5000)
```

In A column of m1 sheet if have date values:

```
2013.06.29  15:40:00
2013.06.21  18:35:00
etc.
```

I got `#VALUE!` error.

If I try only the part it work with:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(YEAR('m1'!$A$2:$A$5000)=2013))
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY('m1'!$A$2:$A$5000)=5))
```

but doesn't work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM('m1'!$A$2:$A$5000)=26))
```

for only on value it works:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM('m1'!A10)=26))
```

but for array don't:

```
**=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM('m1'!A10:A15)=26))**
```

What is the problem with:

```
SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM('m1'!A10:A15)=26))
```

Comment: @ScottCraner what do you want? You want something like this: `=2011*24*3*[Any Value]`  Or  `=[AllValues=2011]*[AllValues=24]*[AllValues=3]*[Any Value]` . You can you can try an array formula.

Comment: @RafaBG 1. not my question I just edited the original to make more readable.  2. Gary's Student has the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *WEEKNUM()* function cannot return an array, therefore it cannot be used with the *SUMPRODUCT()* function, but there are easy workarounds.

See Barry Houdini's reply here:

[Mr Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/288755-use-weeknum-sumproduct.html)

**EDIT#1:**

For the *WEEKNUM()* function the following **will** work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKNUM('m1'!A10:A15+0)=26))
```